# LINQ query for finding Parent by Child

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to EF\LINQ. How to rewrite such sql query in LINQ:

```
SELECT Pacient_ID FROM VisitDates WHERE ID in 
(SELECT visitDate_ID from    Reviews WHERE comments LIKE N'%name%')
```

Problem is that I can't access colums created by EF in LINQ query (visitDate_ID, Pacient_ID)
I'v tried to do something like this, but it is very slow:

```
List<Pacient> found = new List<Pacient>();
            List<Pacient> pacients = db.Pacients.Include(p => p.visits.Select(w => w.reviews)).ToList();
            bool k = false;
            foreach (Pacient p in pacients)
            {
                foreach (VisitDate date in p.visits)
                {
                    foreach (Review r in date.reviews)
                    {
                        if (r.comments.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()))
                        {
                            found.Add(p);
                            k = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (k)
                    {
                        k = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your `Pacient` entity look like?

Comment: Is it possible to give Entity Object structure, difficult for me to understand from your code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity is Pacient supposed to be Patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what your SQL query asked for:

```
var results=db.VisitDates
  .Where(vd=>vd.Reviews.Any(r=>r.comments.Contains("name")))
  .Select(vd=>vd.Pacient_ID);
```

.ToLower() stuff isn't required (usually) because the comparison is handled by the database, which by default does case insensitive comparisons, and adding them may cause the query to run significantly slower.

If you want pacients, then it'd be:

```
var results=db.Pacients
  .Where(p=>p.VisitDates.Any(vd=>vd.Reviews.Any(r=>r.comments.Contains("name"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the the nesting of foreach by this line :

```
var found =(from p in pacients where p.visits.Any(date=>date.reviews.Any
            (r=>r.comments.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())) 
            select p).ToList();
```